# Check if set $V$ of functions $f$ so $f''(x)+x^2f'(x)-3f(x)=0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Good night, i try to check this problem but i'm a little confused. Can someone help me?

Let $V$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$. And $V$ the set of functions $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ twice differentiable  such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $f''(x)+x^2f'(x)-3f(x)=0$  Check if $V$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$.

> Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f,g \in V$. We need check if 
>   $f(x)+g(x)\in V$ and $af(x) \in V$

Can someone give me some hint? Thanks. I really dont know how prove $f(x)+g(x) \in V$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Let $h=f+g$.  What is $h''(x)+x^2h'(x)-3h(x)$?

Similarly, let $k=\alpha f$.  What is $k''(x)+x^2k'(x)-3k(x)$?

Comment: Thanks Mr. Peterson!